# Dual Boot Ubuntu and Windows on Two Separate Hard Drives

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-8

I dual booted my desktop with windows first onto a solid state, and then ubuntu onto a normal hard drive. Then I had the problem of not having the option of booting into Windows anymore. I am not sure where it went and I have tried boot-repair. I am pretty sure I did not over write it because I can see the solid state drive in my Ubuntu desktop and it has all the "Windows program files, etc."

Can you help me figure out how to get my boot menu to show both ubuntu and windows?
What are some things I can try at this point?

Comment: Are both systems installed in BIOS boot mode or both installed in UEFI mode. You should have have Windows in UEFI and Ubuntu in BIOS or vice-versa. If both are in same boot mode run this: `sudo update-grub`

Comment: @oldfred the sudo-update-grub didn't work... I am considering just reinstalling it all together, but before I do, would unplugging my hard drive one at a time work to see if it boots up, or is that just stupid?

Comment: Unplugging drive is often suggested if you are willing to do that. Otherwise when you install, you have to make sure BIOS is set to boot from the drive and you install boot loaders to the correctly drive, which is not always automatically correct. But if a newer system, you still have to be sure to install in same boot mode, either both UEFI or both BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand correctly, but if you mean not having to re-install programs, I see several options:

1. Use Application Mover to migrate them from the HDD to the SSD before formatting Win 7 on the HDD.
2. Leave them where they are; (don't format Win 7* on the HDD), and run them from SSD through shortcuts.
3. Use portable applications versions when possible, and locate them on the HDD. Also install the application "PortableApps" with it's own Start Menu to access them like installed versions.
4. Install new programs (installer versions) on a folder in the HDD.. this may make them slightly slower (probably unnoticeable), but save you space on the SSD.
5. For your final question: When you install programs you most always get prompted to decide where you want them installed, so instead of C:\Program files, just change the drive letter to X:\Program files. If you leave Win 7 on the HDD intact, you can keep installing programs there, and the user start menu will go to the X:\Users\your user acct\Application Data\program name. A part of each installation goes to the Windows folder which can't be moved but it's a minimal part.

Leaving Win 7 on HDD intact, you can even keep using the same User Profile folder setting the same folder in the new installation, as the "Users" folder, or the User Profile folder. The larger temps are located in the user folder (C:\Users\Your user acct\Local Settings\Temp and Internet Temp files), the System temp files are in C:\WINDOWS\Temp but system temps are a lot less... and you can clean them regularly through Start\Run\type: "temp" and the System Temp folder opens.

Comment: I meant I wanted to show a boot up menu in BIOS when I start my computer asking me to boot into Windows 8 or Ubuntu. Right now Windows 8 is not available because it is on the solid state. The boot menu only shows Ubuntu which boots from the hard disk drive.

Answer (score 0):

Before you do anything further, make sure you have a backup of any information or data that is important to you on either your Windows drive, or your Ubuntu drive.  Reconfiguring your partitions can go horribly wrong, and doing bit-level recovery does not always work.

You may have overwritten your EUFI partition.

You may have changed some of your BIOS, so your computer is not booting to the Windows drive.

Windows does prefer have the first physical drive as it's system drive; I have seen weird behavior from Windows when it is not on the first physical drive.

Grub2 is the usual boot loader for Linux.  There is a lot of documentation on the Internet on using it.  Google is your friend.